# Show for i.i.d. r.v., $Y_n /n \rightarrow 0$ a.s. $\Leftrightarrow$ $E|Y_1| < \infty$

Tags: random-variables, independence

I'm working on Durrett, exercise 2.3.15.

Let $(Y_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be sequence of iid rvs. I want to show that

$Y_n /n \rightarrow 0$ a.s.  $\Leftrightarrow$   $E|Y_1| < \infty$

What I have tried:
$$Y_n /n \rightarrow 0 \text{ a.s.} \Leftrightarrow \\ \forall \varepsilon \gt 0, P(|Y_n| \geq n\varepsilon \ \text {i.o})=0 \Leftrightarrow\\ \forall \varepsilon \gt 0, P(|Y_n| \lt n\varepsilon \ \text {ev})=1 \Leftrightarrow\\ \forall \varepsilon \gt 0, lim_{n \to \infty}P(\bigcap_{k \geq n}|Y_k| \lt k\varepsilon )=1  \  \Leftrightarrow\\ \forall \varepsilon \gt 0, lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k \geq n}P(|Y_k| \lt k\varepsilon )=1 \Leftrightarrow\\ \forall \varepsilon \gt 0, lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k \geq n}P(|Y_1| \lt k\varepsilon )=1$$

which is a dead end. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @FedericoTedeschi But we need a.s. convergence...

Comment: Ok: I dropped my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
For any non-negative RV X, we have $$E(X)\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X\ge n) < E(X) +1.$$ This, combined with Borel-Cantelli, will give you your desired equivalence between $P(Y_n > n\epsilon\;i.o.)=0$ and $E(|Y|) < \infty.$

Comment: In the first ineq, shouldn't $ n$ start from 0?

Comment: How do I get the second inequality?

Comment: $P(X\ge 0)=1,$ so that term should be easy to sort out. Both inequalities can be obtained from the fact that $$\lfloor X\rfloor = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1(X\ge n).$$ I don’t believe I’m making an off by one error but invite you to check.

Comment: @izimath: You are right: the proper inequality is: $E(X)\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X\ge n) < E(X) +1$. So, yes, it should start from $0$. The reason is that, in this way, it's like replacing all values between $n$ and $n+1$ ($\forall n \geq 0$) with $n+1$, so you are over-estimating $E(X)$ but under-estimating $E(X+1)$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks. The floor function is very helpful. Now I get that Borel cantelli gives me one direction but I don't see the other way around.

Comment: @izimath I think converse BC would give you the other way too but haven’t thought it through in detail.